# Flutter Install Gradle Issues

Tags: gradle, installation, flutter

I'm trying to get a basic **hello world** project running using flutter. These are the steps that I have taken to install Flutter on a windows machine, running Window 10 Pro.

1. Downloaded `flutter_windows_v0.9.4-beta.zip` and extracted to `c:\src\`
2. Add location to environment settings ... `C:\src\flutter`
3. Downloaded and installed Android Studio and Setup an emulator using ADV Manager.
4. Downloaded and installed Visual Studio Code
5. Added Dart 2.19.0 Extension
6. Added Flutter 2.19.0 Extension
7. Run Flutter doctor

```
    [flutter] flutter doctor
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [√] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.9.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063], locale en-GB)
    [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    [√] Android Studio (version 3.2)
        X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
        X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    [√] VS Code (version 1.28.2)
    [√] Connected devices (1 available)
```

8. Create a new flutter project
9. Deleted code under Test folder
10. Replaced code in `main.dart` with ...

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(Center(
        child: Text(
          "this is a test",
          textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        ),
      ));
    }
```

11. Ran project and get the following error ...

```
    Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
    * Error running Gradle:
    Exit code 1 from: C:\Users\to0589\Desktop\flutter projects\asad\android\gradlew.bat app:properties:
    Project evaluation failed including an error in afterEvaluate {}. Run with --stacktrace for details of the afterEvaluate {} error.
    
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * Where:
    Build file 'C:\Users\to0589\Desktop\flutter projects\asad\android\app\build.gradle' line: 25
    
    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    > Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
       > Could not find lint-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.2).
         Searched in the following locations:
             https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle-api/26.1.2/lint-gradle-api-26.1.2.jar
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 1s
    Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.
    Exited (sigterm)
```

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong please  Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

That's not a problem in your install. This is a problem that many people are facing with current flutter version.

It's [already fixed](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/23397). However, it's not yet released to the most stable version.

If you change the `flutter channel` to `master`, you'll see that it will run normally.

You can use the master channel for now and then switch it back to `dev`.

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade

# to see all the channels, run
flutter channel
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming that this issue is part of the flutter build. It’s difficult enough trying to stumble into using a new programming framework and language without having to deal with issues in tooling. Thanks for taking the time to help with a newbie to flutter.

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/23397

In short, following Mahi-K from the above link, you have to edit `$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}
```

In the gradle wrapper properties `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` you may also have to change it to 4.6 or above

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This resolved the issue in the v0.9.4 Beta branch.

Answer (score 0):

Open the root flutter folder in your computer, and open the gradle folder in that root folder (For example C:\flutter\package\flutter_tool\gradle) and add '**google()**' to the buildscript. It fixed the issue for me.

flutter root folder:
[image]

Add 'google()' in the buildscript:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

update flutter or use one of the  previous version of gradle by changing the class path in this section.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}}
```