# Flutter build apk - please update your settings.gradle file

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, dart, mobile

Flutter run works perfectly fine on mac os
But when I try to build a release apk version of my app it throws a couple of gradle errors:

```
Plugin Project preferences not found please update settings.gradle
Plugin Project :drawer behavior not found please update settings.gardle
Plugin Project :Google-maps not found please update settings.gradle
```

Comment: OK, why don't you update settings.gradle?

Comment: there is nothing in settings.gradle file to update

Comment: ```include ':app'

def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-dashboard.plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```

Comment: this is the code inside settings.gradle

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin do u have any idea?

Comment: This question doesn't help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998515/

Comment: I fixed it by just changing my gradle versions and adjusting name til they do not conflict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the old version of settings.gradle shown below. The new version wasn't working for me either but once i set the old one, it started working and not showing that error

```
  include ':app'

def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()

def plugins = new Properties()
def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
    pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
}

plugins.each { name, path ->
    def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
    include ":$name"
    project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
}
```

Answer (score 14):

> I've found that the problem is related to `settings.gradle`
>   Using an old version of the file everything works.
>   In my specific case moor_ffi was not built and also the shared library libsqlite was not included in the apk.
>
> this is the working file `settings.gradle`:
>
> ```
> include ':app'
>
> def flutterProjectRoot = rootProject.projectDir.parentFile.toPath()
>
> def plugins = new Properties()
> def pluginsFile = new File(flutterProjectRoot.toFile(), '.flutter-plugins')
> if (pluginsFile.exists()) {
>     pluginsFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -> plugins.load(reader) }
> }
>
> plugins.each { name, path ->
>     def pluginDirectory = flutterProjectRoot.resolve(path).resolve('android').toFile()
>     include ":$name"
>     project(":$name").projectDir = pluginDirectory
> }
> ```
>
> this is the more recent **not working** `settings.gradle`:
>
> ```
> include ':app'
>
> def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
> def properties = new Properties()
>
> assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
> localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }
>
> def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
> assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
> apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"
> ```

Reference Link 
[GitHub Flutter Issus](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55827#issuecomment-623779910)

Comment: I'm having the same issue with moor_ffi but your solution doesnt work for me :(